# Relation not being generated

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, schema.yml

I have the following schema.yml

```
Person:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    joomla_user_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: false, unique: true }
    name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    email: { type: string(200), notnull: true }
    organisation_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: false }
    position: { type: string(100), notnull: false }
    phone: { type: string(25), notnull: false }
    afterhours: { type: string(100), notnull: false }
    mobile: { type: string(100), notnull: false }
    profile_photo_url: { type: string(250), notnull: false }
    profile_short: { type: string(2500), notnull: false }
    profile_long: { type: clob (16000000), notnull: false }
    link1_type: {  type: string(255), notnull: false}
    link1: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
    link2_type: {  type: string(255), notnull: false}
    link2: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
    link3_type: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
    link3: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
    link4_type: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
    link4: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
    fax: { type: string(100), notnull: false }
    address: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
    region_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    notes: { type: clob(16777777), notnull: false }

  relations:
    Organisation: { local: organisation_id }
    IndustryGroups: { class: IndustryGroup, refClass: PersonIndustryGroup, local: person_id, foreign: industry_group_id  }
    Region: { local: region_id }
    RegionServiced: { class: PersonRegionList,refClass: PersonRegion, local: person_id, foreign: region_id  }
    EmailLists: { class: EmailList, refClass: PersonEmailList, local: person_id, foreign: email_list_id  }
    CategoryTags: { class: CategoryTag, refClass: PersonCategoryTag, local: person_id, foreign: category_tag_id  }
    JoomlaUser: { class: JosUser, local: joomla_user_id }
    CertifiedProfessional: { class: CertifiedProfessional, local: id, foreign: person_id }

PersonRegion:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    person_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    region_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Person:
      class: Person
      local: person_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Region:
      class: Region
      local: region_id
      onDelete: RESTRICT

PersonIndustryGroup:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    person_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    industry_group_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Person:
      class: Person
      local: person_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    IndustryGroup:
      class: IndustryGroup
      local: industry_group_id
      onDelete: RESTRICT

IndustryGroup:
  actAs:
    Sortable: ~
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }

PersonEmailList:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    person_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    email_list_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Person:
      class: Person
      local: person_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    EmailList:
      class: EmailList
      local: email_list_id
      onDelete: RESTRICT

EmailList:
  actAs:
    Sortable: ~
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    mailchimp_name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    on_signup: { type: boolean }
    member_only: { type: boolean }
```

I have recently added the RegionServiced relation - this is the only relation where nothing is being generated for in BasePersonForm.class.php

There is no error message when I run `./symfony doctrine:build --forms --filters --model`
, but the there is no person_region_list widget as I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `class` option:

```
relations:
[..]
    RegionServiced: { class: Region, refClass: PersonRegion, local: person_id, foreign: region_id  }
[..]
```